# Separation of plane by line given two points

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, line

Given two points with x-y coordinates I have a line specified. Now I want to distinguish in an 2-d numpy array the points left to the line from those on the right.

The following code does the trick - but the double loop hurts my religious feelings (towards numpy). There must be a smarter way?

```
def myline(a_x,a_y,b_x,b_y):
start=np.zeros((100,100))
for x in range(100):
    for y in range(100):
        val= (b_x - a_x)*(y - a_y) - (x - a_x)*(b_y - a_y)
        if val<=0:
            start[x,y]=1
return start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be vectorized using `ogrid`:

```
x, y = np.ogrid[:100, :100]
start = (b_x - a_x)*(y - a_y) - (x - a_x)*(b_y - a_y) <= 0
```

This will give you a boolean mask. If you want some other dtype

```
start = start.astype(np.int)
```